# Intuitive way to think about completeness and compactness

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

I've been struggling with questions that tackle complete/compact spaces and I think the reason why is that I cannot find an intuitive way to think about these concepts. This means that I find it difficult to spot the key idea needed to solve a problem. I've been thinking of completeness as not missing any potential limit points, but I have no clue how to think about a compact space. Does anyone have any more conceptual ways of thinking about these properties?

Comment: Compact spaces behave like finite spaces.

Answer (score 1):

Let's start to only think about compact space in $\mathbb{R}^n$. In $\mathbb{R}^n$ compact spaces are the closed and bounded subpaces , meaning that there is "no infinities". Indeed the space is bounded so we can put it inside a ball so it doesn't have infinite, and it's closed so there is no infinities on the boarder. For example, the open subset $(a,b)$ has two infinities at each endpoint since we can go infinitely close to $a$ but never approached it.

Now you can generalize and think how compactness as "no infinities". You can find that in the definition of compactness that say that every cover admits a finite one, this is just the generalization of what compact means in $\mathbb{R}^n$.